# Rails 3.1 Model with has_many through Naming Issue - ThisIsModelName.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, naming-conventions, has-many-through

I need to create a join model called CarStoreTracker for Car and Store with both having many of each other.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :carstoretrackers        # It seems to work
  has_many :stores, :through => :carstoretrackers  # I bet the naming is not being recognized by Rails convention
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :carstoretrackers        # It seems to work
  has_many :cars, :through => :carstoretrackers  # Same issue
end

class CarStoreTracker < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :car
end
```

The CarStoreTracker has

```
car_id and store_id on its table.
```

When I run:

```
 > CarStoreTracker.first.car
 > CarStoreTracker.first.store
```

They both work.

But

> Store.first.cars
>   Car.first.stores
>   Store.carstoretrackers
>   Car.carstoretrackers

Non of them work.
     NameError: uninitialized constant "CURRENTMODEL"::Carproducttracker

So, I scrapped the CarProductTracker and I just used the name Tracker for model and everything works.

What's happening? What the name convention is for Rails in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put underscores after each word when defining has_many and other relationships.

So it would be :car_store_trackers

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It was hard to find it out.